# measuring SWT / JFace column header padding size

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a number of tables in an eclipse SWT application. They are Table/TableViewer tables and consist of a header, a row down the left with text and a series of graphics going across. There are 32 columns other than the text column, numbered from 0 to 31. 
On Windows 7 and XP in classic mode, the text is fine, but in XP normal mode, they are truncated so they appear to go 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. etc. There is clearly enough room for the text either way.

If I just set the default width to 28 instead of 25, as I found it, they are then fine, but obviously that isn't very good as then I need more room for the interface in Windows 7 and XP Classic, where it was already ok.
I tried getting average width from fontmetrics but the text comes back as 5, in all modes. I can't find any way of either reducing of the padding (which would be the best way), or finding out how much padding there is (which would do). Do I need to draw the column headers manually?

ps: Sorry for the JFace / SWT, have only just started with this and not clear on the differences yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `TableColumn#pack()` should give a column exactly the width it needs to display its content without wasting any space or truncating its content. This includes the column's header text.

Comment: Need to keep the biggest column, as obviously (although not on win7) the single digit columns are smaller, but after a redraw it can now do the resize between XP and XP in classic mode. Strangely enough in Win7 it comes back bigger than it was before, even though it wasn't truncating in that, so the interface has grown, but at least it is consistant, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TableLayout for a more dynamic size calculation of your table headers. A good starting point is the following blog article: http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2007/11/one-of-less-prominent-novelties-in.html

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure I am following. The columns are non resizeable apart from the label, and have no relationship to the size of the window. In an ideal world they need to be as small as they possibly can without clipping the text. TableLayout doesn't seem to have anything to give me the smallest space possible